# Codename One: How to reduce an image size to fit within a Dialog box?

Tags: codenameone

I have this piece of Codename One code to display an image (supplied by the user by choosing a file or taking a photo) in a dialog box:

```
private void showConfirmUploadDialogBox(String photoFilePathString) throws IOException {
    Image photoImage = Image.createImage(photoFilePathString);
    ScaleImageLabel scaleImageLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(photoImage);
    Dialog confirmUploadDialog = new Dialog();
    Button cancelButton = Screen.getCancelButton(confirmUploadDialog);
    Button confirmBecomeInfluencerButton = getConfirmUploadButton(confirmUploadDialog, photoFilePathString);
    confirmUploadDialog.setTitle("Confirm Upload");
    confirmUploadDialog.add(scaleImageLabel);
    confirmUploadDialog.add(cancelButton);
    confirmUploadDialog.add(confirmBecomeInfluencerButton);
    confirmUploadDialog.showDialog();
}
```

The problem is the user can choose a photo that is really big and it shadows the entire dialog or screen (and it is not scrollable).

**I'd like to solve this problem by automatically reduce the image to a constrained size proportionately, say max. of 2/3 of the height (of the device). How do I do this? (I've tried to setHeight or use a TableLayout constraint but it does not work.)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding:

```
    int displayHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();
    Image scaledPhotoImage = photoImage.scaled(-1, displayHeight / 2);
    ScaleImageLabel scaleImageLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(scaledPhotoImage);
```